# SitesApp addHostedAttachment Limits?

Tags: google-apps-script

We need to host a few thousand small images (around 30k each) in a Google Sites page. As far [as I have read](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96770) and understand there is no limit in Sites other than the storage limit at domain level and a max attachment size of 50MB (per attachment).

I am fetching the images from their original host and then add them as attachment, using code lines like below (simplified)

```
var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(SITES_PAGE_URL);
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(PHOTO_URL);
var imageBlob = resp.getBlob();
var attachment = page.addHostedAttachment(imageBlob);
```

The problem is that I cannot add more than 501 images, after that I start catching this funny and misleading error: "Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action." on addHostedAttachment

Any ideas ?? (I am in pain ;)

Comment: I have entered a new issue in the issue tracker asking for Help!!! http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2304

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a limitation. You can only host 500 images per page. In the past, I have overcome this problem by having multiple pages with an index. Something like page1,page2 etc.